# How can i group by list in C#

Tags: c#, sql, list, linq

Let's say i have a list like example below:

```
var myList = {
   {id = 1, price = 30},
   {id = 2, price = 20},
   {id = 3, price = 40},
   {id = 3, price = 60},
   {id = 1, price = 70},
   {id = 1, price = 20},
   {id = 2, price = 110},
};
```

I can do what i want in sql like this:

```
SELECT id,SUM(price) FROM table GROUP BY id
```

But i want to do this in C#. I think i can use LINQ for this but i am not sure. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Linq `GroupBy()` and `Sum()`

```
var myList = new[] {
    new { id = 1, price = 30},
    new { id = 2, price = 20},
    new { id = 3, price = 40},
    new { id = 3, price = 60},
    new { id = 1, price = 70},
    new { id = 1, price = 20},
    new { id = 2, price = 110},
    };


var result = myList.GroupBy(x => x.id).Select(x => new { id = x.Key, price = x.Sum(y => y.price)});
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/MhzJab

Comment: But i don't have an array. I have a generic list. like List<MyObj> myList. When i type myList.GroupBy(). It says myList doesn't have a GroupBy method

Comment: @Mirzaloglu `using System.Linq;` - see my example at https://dotnetfiddle.net/MhzJab

Comment: Thank you! But i have to ask one more thing. I have an error like: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Test>'

Comment: I don't know your class definition but the `Select()` part should look something like this `.Select(x => new Test(){id = x.Key, price = x.Sum(y => y.price)}).ToList()`